# what is difference between Get Request and Get method of RequestsLibrary robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Both have same parameter except `Get Request` have extra one json

Here is one example

```
Create Session  httpbin     http://httpbin.org
&{params}=   Create Dictionary   key=value     key2=value2
${resp}=     Get Request  httpbin  /get    params=${params}
log to console  ${resp.content}
```

In line 3 get method takes parameter , can we use Get Request and Get method together.I am unable to relate how both method works in line 3

Comment: What do you mean by "get method"?  What is the "get method"? I don't see anywhere in your code where you're calling "get method".

Comment: in line 3 /get , is it get method of RequestsLibrary or parameter ? here is defination of library      def get_request(
            self,
            alias,
            uri,
            headers=None,
            json=None,
            params=None,
            allow_redirects=None,
            timeout=None):

Comment: In your code, `/get` is a parameter. It's used to build the URL that the library will call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it comes in which argument of Get Request method? for example we specify like Json=some data  param=/service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the keyword `Get Request` after having imported `RequestsLibrary`, that keyword calls the method `get_request` that is part of the definition of the `RequestsLibrary` class. They aren't different, one is just the public interface to the internal method. When robot sees you call the `Get Request` keyword, it scans the libraries for a method named `get_request`. The method in the library is then called.

Any parameter that the `get_request` method takes is perfectly valid when calling the keyword. Again, the keyword and the method are identical. They are exactly the same thing.

Apparently, the `json` parameter that you are asking about was added fairly recently. I guess either that version of the library hasn't been released yet, or the documentation hasn't been updated.

If the version of `RequestsLibrary` on your computer has the `json` parameter, you can use that in your test.

Comment: Thanks but i have declared any http library , how it used get method of http

Comment: @madhur: the requests library makes the http call.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. is difference between Get Request and Get method of RequestsLibrary robot framework. like i have mention both have same argument in definition except json.

Comment: @madhur: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question. "RequestsLibrary" has no "get method". It has a keyword named "Get Request", and another keyword named "Get" which is just an alias for "Get Request".

Comment: Please refer line 453 and 491  https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/src/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py

Comment: Ok, it appears that `json` is just a new parameter added in the past few months. Either it hasn't been released, or the documentation hasn't been updated.

Comment: but is there any difference in both method . or we should always use Get Request method to received the response . is there any specific purpose to use Get method.

Comment: Thanks a ton Bryan